# Index of element from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to process a list of emails, cut them and make the output with counter of iterations

```
MailList = [email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com, email3@gmail.com] # I have a list with emails
# I need to process them and get next output: "User%number% is email1" I'm using something like:
for c in MailList:
    print('user'+ ' is '+c[0:7]) # what I need to insert here to get desirable counter for my output?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want this:

```
MailList = ["email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com", "email3@gmail.com"]

for index, value in enumerate(MailList):
    print('user {} is {}'.format(index, value.split("@")[0]))
```

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for details on `enumerate`.

Comment: @AntonJakimenko I'm glad I could help you! If this answer (or another) solved your problem, it would be great if you could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the emails with `@` :

```
>>> MailList = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com', 'email3@gmail.com']
>>> for i in MailList :
...   print ('user'+ ' is {}'.format(i.split('@')[0]) )
... 
user is email1
user is email2
user is email3
```

Answer (score 0):

using `itertools.takewhile`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> MailList = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com', 'email3@gmail.com']
>>> for x in MailList:
...     print("user is {}".format("".join(itertools.takewhile(lambda x:x!='@',x))))
... 
user is email1
user is email2
user is email3
```

using `index`:

```
>>> for x in MailList:
...     print("user is {}".format(x[:x.index('@')]))
... 
user is email1
user is email2
user is email3
```

using `find`:

```
>>> for x in MailList:
...     print("user is {}".format(x[:x.find('@')]))
... 
user is email1
user is email2
user is email3
```